# JavaScript function; works locally but not for Lambda Minibootcamp

Tags: node.js, object, testing, methods, npm

This is driving me crazy. Any help would be appreciated. The situation:

An already existing object, storeItem has two relevant properties, price, and discountPercentage. I am to write a function (from outside of the object), called addCalculateDiscountPrice, that adds a method, called calculateDiscountPrice to storeItem that returns the discounted price.

Here is the code:

```
function addCalculateDiscountPriceMethod(storeItem) {
  // add a method to the storeItem object called 'calculateDiscountPrice'
  // this method should multiply the storeItem's 'price' and  'discountPercentage' to get the discount
  // the method then subtracts the discount from the price and returns the discounted price
  // example: 
  // price -> 20
  // discountPercentage -> .2
  // discountPrice = 20 - (20 * .2)
  storeItem.calculateDiscountPrice = function() {
    var discount = this.discountPercentage;
    var saved = this.price * discount;
    var finalPrice = this.price - saved;
    return finalPrice;
  };
}
```

This is part of the Lambda JavaScript Mini Bootcamp, which has me install npm inside of each  assignment directory after cloning it with git.  When I run this same code (with the relevant already existing object, of course) using jsnode in a terminal, I get the expected output of 16 when using the example variables in the comments. However, when I run npm test I get the following errors:

```
FAIL  tests/test.js
  ● addCalculateDiscountPriceMethod(storeItem) › should add the method    'calculateDiscountPrice' to the store item object

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'calculateDiscountPrice' of undefined

  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/test.js:209:64)

  ● addCalculateDiscountPriceMethod(storeItem) › should return the discount price from the new 'calculateDiscountPrice' method
```

I have rewritten this code multiple times trying to make this pass npm test. I've tried using bracket notation as well as returning the obviously simple calculation on one single line (return price - (price * discountPercentage)), and, in addition to the original attempt, both of these retries worked just fine on the live terminal nodejs session.

So why isn't it working for npm test? What am I not seeing?

Update: Here is the relevant test code from the npm test file:

```
describe('addCalculateDiscountPriceMethod(storeItem)', function() {
  var storeItem = {
    price: 80,
    discountPercentage: 0.1
  };
  var storeItem2 = {
    price: 5,
    discountPercentage: 0.5
  };

  it('should add the method \'calculateDiscountPrice\' to the store item  object', function() {
  expect(exercises.addCalculateDiscountPriceMethod(storeItem).calculateDiscountPrice).toBeDefined();
 expect(exercises.addCalculateDiscountPriceMethod(storeItem2).calculateDiscount Price).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('should return the discount price from the new \'calculateDiscountPrice\' method', function() {
expect(exercises.addCalculateDiscountPriceMethod(storeItem).calculateDiscountPrice()).toBe(72);
expect(exercises.addCalculateDiscountPriceMethod(storeItem2).calculateDiscountPrice()).toBe(2.5);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is already telling you that storeItem is undefined, since it is the function argument and you are doing nothing with it before trying to add the function then the issue must be with the test itself.

Look at the test file and check if arguments are being passed to your function. Or use

```
console.log(arguments);
```

Inside the function, arguments is a reserved word that contains the parameters passed to the function call.

Edit: looking at the test it is chaining this two calls

```
addCalculateDiscountPriceMethod(storeItem)
    .calculateDiscountPrice()
```

Since you are not returning anything it is calling calculateDisconutPrice on undefined therefore you must return storeItem in addCalculateDiscountPriceMethod.

Comment: Edit with the solution!

Comment: Insidro I understand your explanation but what exactly would you write to fix this?

Comment: return storeItem at the end of you method

Comment: Yeah then it must be the npm test file because that didn't work.

Comment: return it AFTER assigning the calculateDiscountPrice function